# ng serve command generates error Duplicate identifier 'export='

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Whenever I run ng serve or npm start, I get the following error : **error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.**
in two files.

First one : **module.d.ts**

```
declare module "module" {
    export = NodeJS.Module;
}
```

second one : **index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'module' {
    var mod: {
        config: () => any;
        id: string;
        uri: string;
    }
    export = mod;
}
```

- 1: I changed the names won't work.
- 2: delete node module and do npm install not working either.
- 3: some exclude terminology also not working.

Please provide some solution.
[check image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbKtt.png)